# jquery Ui Auto Complete Static ServerSide Data source

Tags: asp.net, jquery, user-interface, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

jquery Ui AutoComplete has a property that named Source.
i want to value this property with static datasource for example generic list or filled dataset on my asp.net application.
is it possible?
would you please give me an example?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a perfectly good example on the demo page

1. Go to http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#options
2. Expand the "source" example

Edit: Actually, the default example source is even better.

1. Go to http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/
2. Click the "View Source" link under the demo

Comment: Hi Phil . I already had seen this link. it is javascript array and it is client side. but my datasource is server side (Dataset , DataDatable , generic List ,...)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890093. Take note of the comment regarding wrapping each value in quotes.