# Converting string of binary to hex

Tags: c#, binary, hex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting long string of binary to hex c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612306/converting-long-string-of-binary-to-hex-c-sharp)

nyI'm looking for a way to convert a string of binary to a hex string.

the binary string has four positions.
the binary string looks something like this

```
string binarystring= "1011";
```

output string should be like this

```
output string="B";
```

is there any way to convert a string of binary into hex?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612306/converting-long-string-of-binary-to-hex-c-sharp

Comment: I just ran a search on Google for "c# convert binary string to hex" and the first 2 results were http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612306/converting-long-string-of-binary-to-hex-c-sharp and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617284/c-sharp-how-convert-large-hex-string-to-binary and in **both**, the answer you're looking for is in the question, highlighted too. So what's your excuse for being lazy?

Answer (score 16):

```
Convert.ToInt32("1011", 2).ToString("X");
```

For more information about the string value used with `ToString()` as its parameter, check the following documentation:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This Q has been marked as a duplicate. Your answer is better than the one in the other Q, you should post it there too!