# How to convert a string of bits to a HEX

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, binary, hex, converters

I've found loads of info about converting a byte array to a hex string, but unfortunatly it isn't what I want. I have a 15 part string consisting of 1s and 0s and I want to convert it to a hex value. I.E. 111110000000000 = 7C00 like on this [link](https://www.binaryhexconverter.com/binary-to-hex-converter). How can I do that in C# for Unity?

Thank you in advance,

Robert

Comment: Did you see this one?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612306/converting-long-string-of-binary-to-hex-c-sharp

Comment: I didn't see that one before. Thank you