# C# line break every n characters

Tags: c#, split, line, character

Suppose I have a string with the text: "THIS IS A TEST". How would I split it every n characters? So if n was 10, then it would display:

```
"THIS IS A "
"TEST"
```

..you get the idea. The reason is because I want to split a very big line into smaller lines, sort of like word wrap. I think I can use string.Split() for this, but I have no idea how and I'm confused.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Split a string into equal chunks each of size 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450774/c-sharp-split-a-string-into-equal-chunks-each-of-size-4)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Splitting a string into chunks of a certain size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450774/splitting-a-string-into-chunks-of-a-certain-size)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Splitting a string / number every Nth Character / Number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133377/splitting-a-string-number-every-nth-character-number)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Let's borrow an implementation from [my answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5283/better-way-to-write-a-string-slicer/5311#5311) on code review. This inserts a line break every *n* characters:

```
public static string SpliceText(string text, int lineLength) {
  return Regex.Replace(text, "(.{" + lineLength + "})", "$1" + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Edit:
To return an array of strings instead:

```
public static string[] SpliceText(string text, int lineLength) {
  return Regex.Matches(text, ".{1," + lineLength + "}").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this can be used to handle efficiently extreme large files :

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetChunks(this string sourceString, int chunkLength)
{  
    using(var sr = new StringReader(sourceString))
    {
        var buffer = new char[chunkLength];
        int read;
        while((read= sr.Read(buffer, 0, chunkLength)) == chunkLength)
        {
            yield return new string(buffer, 0, read);
        }        
    }
}
```

Actually, this works for any `TextReader`. `StreamReader` is the most common used `TextReader`. You can handle very large text files (IIS Log files, SharePoint Log files, etc) without having to load the whole file, but reading it line by line.

Comment: The general idea is good but isn't this approach missing the last characters if `source.Length` is not a multiple of `chunkLength`?

Comment: If you  want to  read all string(include last string which length is less than `chunkLength`),just use this condition:`while ((read = sr.Read(buffer, 0, chunkLength)) !=0)`

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use a regex for this. Here is an example:

```
//in this case n = 10 - adjust as needed
List<string> groups = (from Match m in Regex.Matches(str, ".{1,10}") 
                       select m.Value).ToList();

string newString = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, lst.ToArray());
```

Refer to this question for details:
[Splitting a string into chunks of a certain size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450774/c-sharp-split-a-string-into-equal-chunks-each-of-size-4)

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the most optimal way, but without regex:

```
string test = "my awesome line of text which will be split every n characters";
int nInterval = 10;
string res = String.Concat(test.Select((c, i) => i > 0 && (i % nInterval) == 0 ? c.ToString() + Environment.NewLine : c.ToString()));
```

Comment: It's better to use `String.Concat()` instead of a join with an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Coming back to this after doing a code review, there's another way of doing the same without using `Regex`

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SplitText(string text, int length)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i += length)
    {
        yield return text.Substring(i, Math.Min(length, text.Length - i));  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some code that I just wrote:

```
string[] SplitByLength(string line, int len, int IsB64=0) {

    int i;

    if (IsB64 == 1) {
        // Only Allow Base64 Line Lengths without '=' padding
        int mod64 = (len % 4);
        if (mod64 != 0) {
            len = len + (4 - mod64);
        }
    }

    int parts = line.Length / len;
    int frac  = line.Length % len;
    int extra = 0;
    if (frac != 0) {
        extra = 1;
    }
   
    string[] oline = new string[parts + extra];
   
    for(i=0; i < parts; i++) {
        oline[i] = line.Substring(0, len);
        line     = line.Substring(len);
    }
   
    if (extra == 1) {
        oline[i] = line;
    }
    return oline;
}

string CRSplitByLength(string line, int len, int IsB64 = 0)
{
    string[] lines = SplitByLength(line, len, IsB64);
    return string.Join(System.Environment.NewLine, lines);
}

string m = "1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxhyz";

string[] r = SplitByLength(m, 6, 0);

foreach (string item in r) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", item);
}
```