# RSA private key one line format problem c#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, rsa

I have RSA private  keys without format (just one line)
Just example (the key is long like correct key)
like:

```
string rsa = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----MIICXAIBAAKBgQCuMhJ8DYGiSzLw88PvHgMGCJOT+og1i0dfcsmo7jBspwuM+sBq....";
```

I need to fix the string to a string with the correct format probably like:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

The private key with one line format not working in library which  I use.

Is it possible fix it in c# to working format ?
TY

Comment: Is it possible to use a file? that would be better instead of having the key hard-coded

Comment: What library are you using and what is your C# version? Most libraries allow the import of DER encoded keys, i.e. they do not have to be PEM encoded. If you are only concerned about inserting line breaks, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7768475).

Comment: You can use a verbatim string starting `@"` and then embed newlines into it.

Comment: @Topaco I am using MailBee.Net library for sending emails. But key in this oneline format not supported now. I am using net framework 4.8.

Comment: If the key can really only be imported as PEM, try this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/28Vi44. If the PEM format does not work either, post your code, especially the key import. Maybe another format is required.