# HDF5 Example code

Tags: c#, hdf5

Using [HDF5DotNet](http://hdf5.net/), can anyone point me at example code, which will open an hdf5 file, extract the contents of a dataset, and print the contents to standard output?

So far I have the following:

```
        H5.Open();
        var h5 = H5F.open("example.h5", H5F.OpenMode.ACC_RDONLY);
        var dataset = H5D.open(h5, "/Timings/aaPCBTimes");
        var space = H5D.getSpace(dataset);
        var size = H5S.getSimpleExtentDims(space);
```

Then it gets a bit confusing.

I actually want to do some processing on the contents of the dataset but I think once I have dump to standard output I can work it out from there.

UPDATE:  I've hacked around this sufficient to solve my own problem.  I failed to realise a dataset was a multi-array - I thought it was more like a db table.  In the unlikely event anyone is interested,

```
double[,] dataArray = new double[size[0], 6];
var wrapArray = new H5Array<double>(dataArray);
var dataType = H5D.getType(d);
H5D.read(dataset, dataType, wrapArray);
Console.WriteLine(dataArray[0, 0]);
```

Comment: I want to point out that having `H5`, `h5`, `H5F`, `H5S` and `H5D` as variable names is bad form.  The first two differ only by case.  The others by only a single letter.

Comment: Yes.  H5, H5F, H5S, and H5D are all provided by the API - [HDF5DotNet - C++/CLI Wrapper of the HDF5 Library](http://hdf5.net/).  If you follow the link, you can also enjoy H5A, H5E, H5G, H5I, H5L, H5O, H5P, and H5R.  I'm looking for a code sample because I'm not keen to spend much time studying this interface.

Comment: Why don't you add your hack/solution as an answer and accept it?

Comment: Wow. Last time I used HDF5 in .NET I wrapped the P/Invoke calls myself. Glad to see a supported library. Oh, good ol HDF5.

Comment: is there any useable HDF5 library by now? The previous comments should make it sufficiently clear that HDF4DotNet is really not the way to go if you seriously want to use it in a quick and easy way - not to mention the lack of documented examples that are beyond minimalist basics.

Comment: @Sebastian, I just found [this](http://ilnumerics.net/hdf5-interface.html) (commercially licensed) high level API for HDF5.  It looks good, but it's part of a large, expensive project.

Comment: Note that the HDF5 project [now recommends](https://support.hdfgroup.org/projects/hdf.net/) using their P/Invoke wrappers [here](https://github.com/HDFGroup/HDF.PInvoke), and that HDF5DotNet is unmaintained and frozen in 2012.

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
using System;
using HDF5DotNet;

namespace CSharpExample1
{
    class Program
    {
    // Function used with 
    static int myFunction(H5GroupId id, string objectName, Object param)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The object name is {0}", objectName);
        Console.WriteLine("The object parameter is {0}", param);
        return 0;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            // We will write and read an int array of this length.
            const int DATA_ARRAY_LENGTH = 12;

            // Rank is the number of dimensions of the data array.
            const int RANK = 1;

            // Create an HDF5 file.
            // The enumeration type H5F.CreateMode provides only the legal 
            // creation modes.  Missing H5Fcreate parameters are provided
            // with default values.
            H5FileId fileId = H5F.create("myCSharp.h5", 
                                         H5F.CreateMode.ACC_TRUNC);

            // Create a HDF5 group.  
            H5GroupId groupId = H5G.create(fileId, "/cSharpGroup", 0);
            H5GroupId subGroup = H5G.create(groupId, "mySubGroup", 0);   

            // Demonstrate getObjectInfo
            ObjectInfo info = H5G.getObjectInfo(fileId, "/cSharpGroup", true);
            Console.WriteLine("cSharpGroup header size is {0}", info.headerSize);
            Console.WriteLine("cSharpGroup nlinks is {0}", info.nHardLinks);
            Console.WriteLine("cSharpGroup fileno is {0} {1}", 
                 info.fileNumber[0], info.fileNumber[1]);
            Console.WriteLine("cSharpGroup objno is {0} {1}", 
                 info.objectNumber[0], info.objectNumber[1]);
            Console.WriteLine("cSharpGroup type is {0}", info.objectType);


            H5G.close(subGroup);

            // Prepare to create a data space for writing a 1-dimensional 
            // signed integer array.
            ulong[] dims = new ulong[RANK];
            dims[0] = DATA_ARRAY_LENGTH;

            // Put descending ramp data in an array so that we can
            // write it to the file.
            int[] dset_data = new int[DATA_ARRAY_LENGTH];
            for (int i = 0; i < DATA_ARRAY_LENGTH; i++)
                dset_data[i] = DATA_ARRAY_LENGTH - i;

            // Create a data space to accommodate our 1-dimensional array.
            // The resulting H5DataSpaceId will be used to create the 
            // data set.
            H5DataSpaceId spaceId = H5S.create_simple(RANK, dims);

            // Create a copy of a standard data type.  We will use the 
            // resulting H5DataTypeId to create the data set.  We could
            // have  used the HST.H5Type data directly in the call to 
            // H5D.create, but this demonstrates the use of H5T.copy 
            // and the use of a H5DataTypeId in H5D.create.
            H5DataTypeId typeId = H5T.copy(H5T.H5Type.NATIVE_INT);

            // Find the size of the type
            uint typeSize = H5T.getSize(typeId);
            Console.WriteLine("typeSize is {0}", typeSize);

            // Set the order to big endian
            H5T.setOrder(typeId, H5T.Order.BE);

            // Set the order to little endian
            H5T.setOrder(typeId, H5T.Order.LE);

            // Create the data set.
            H5DataSetId dataSetId = H5D.create(fileId, "/csharpExample", 
                                               typeId, spaceId);

            // Write the integer data to the data set.

            H5D.write(dataSetId, new H5DataTypeId(H5T.H5Type.NATIVE_INT),
                              new H5Array<int>(dset_data));

            // If we were writing a single value it might look like this.
            //  int singleValue = 100;
            //  H5D.writeScalar(dataSetId, new H5DataTypeId(H5T.H5Type.NATIVE_INT),
            //     ref singleValue);

            // Create an integer array to receive the read data.
            int[] readDataBack = new int[DATA_ARRAY_LENGTH];

            // Read the integer data back from the data set
            H5D.read(dataSetId, new H5DataTypeId(H5T.H5Type.NATIVE_INT), 
                new H5Array<int>(readDataBack));

            // Echo the data
            for(int i=0;i<DATA_ARRAY_LENGTH;i++)
            {
               Console.WriteLine(readDataBack[i]);
            }  

            // Close all the open resources.
            H5D.close(dataSetId);

            // Reopen and close the data sets to show that we can.
            dataSetId = H5D.open(fileId, "/csharpExample");
            H5D.close(dataSetId);
            dataSetId = H5D.open(groupId, "/csharpExample");
            H5D.close(dataSetId);

            H5S.close(spaceId);
            H5T.close(typeId);
            H5G.close(groupId);

            //int x = 10;
            //H5T.enumInsert<int>(typeId, "myString", ref x);
            //H5G.close(groupId);
            H5GIterateDelegate myDelegate;
            myDelegate = myFunction;
            int x = 9;
            int index = H5G.iterate(fileId, "/cSharpGroup",
                myDelegate, x, 0);

            // Reopen the group id to show that we can.
            groupId = H5G.open(fileId, "/cSharpGroup");
            H5G.close(groupId);

            H5F.close(fileId);

            // Reopen and reclose the file.
            H5FileId openId = H5F.open("myCSharp.h5", 
                                       H5F.OpenMode.ACC_RDONLY);
            H5F.close(openId);
        }
        // This catches all the HDF exception classes.  Because each call
        // generates unique exception, different exception can be handled
        // separately.  For example, to catch open errors we could have used
        // catch (H5FopenException openException).
        catch (HDFException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Processing complete!");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I edited the example since it does not compile: H5G.create -> skip third argument, H5S.create_simple has to get long[] instead of ulong[] as second argument, H5T.getSize returns int instead of uint

Answer (score 7):

So, your start was awesome. I've created some extensions which should help you out. Using this in your code, you should be able to things that make more sense in an object-oriented language, such as (in your case):

```
H5.Open();
var h5FileId= H5F.open("example.h5");
double[,] dataArray = h5FileId.Read2DArray<double>("/Timings/aaPCBTimes");
// or more generically...
T[,] dataArray = h5FileId.Read2DArray<T>("/Timings/aaPCBTimes");
```

Here are the incomplete extensions, I'll look into adding them into the HDF5Net...

```
public static class HdfExtensions
{
    // thank you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133377/splitting-a-string-number-every-nth-character-number
    public static IEnumerable<String> SplitInParts(this String s, Int32 partLength)
    {
        if (s == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("s");
        if (partLength <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("Part length has to be positive.", "partLength");

        for (var i = 0; i < s.Length; i += partLength)
            yield return s.Substring(i, Math.Min(partLength, s.Length - i));
    }

    public static T[] Read1DArray<T>(this H5FileId fileId, string dataSetName)
    {
        var dataset = H5D.open(fileId, dataSetName);
        var space = H5D.getSpace(dataset);
        var dims = H5S.getSimpleExtentDims(space);
        var dataType = H5D.getType(dataset);
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
        {
            int stringLength = H5T.getSize(dataType);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[dims[0] * stringLength];
            H5D.read(dataset, dataType, new H5Array<byte>(buffer));
            string stuff = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
            return stuff.SplitInParts(stringLength).Select(ss => (T)(object)ss).ToArray();
        }
        T[] dataArray = new T[dims[0]];
        var wrapArray = new H5Array<T>(dataArray);
        H5D.read(dataset, dataType, wrapArray);
        return dataArray;
    }

    public static T[,] Read2DArray<T>(this H5FileId fileId, string dataSetName)
    {
        var dataset = H5D.open(fileId, dataSetName);
        var space = H5D.getSpace(dataset);
        var dims = H5S.getSimpleExtentDims(space);
        var dataType = H5D.getType(dataset);
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
        {
             // this will also need a string hack...
        }
        T[,] dataArray = new T[dims[0], dims[1]];
        var wrapArray = new H5Array<T>(dataArray);
        H5D.read(dataset, dataType, wrapArray);
        return dataArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is much more helpful than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working sample:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using HDF5DotNet;
namespace HDF5Test
{
    public class HDFTester
    {
        static int myFunction(H5GroupId id, string objectName, Object param)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The object name is {0}", objectName);
            Console.WriteLine("The object parameter is {0}", param);
            return 0;
        }

        public static void runTest()
        {
            try
            {
                // We will write and read an int array of this length.
                const int DATA_ARRAY_LENGTH = 12;

                // Rank is the number of dimensions of the data array.
                const int RANK = 1;

                // Create an HDF5 file.
                // The enumeration type H5F.CreateMode provides only the legal 
                // creation modes.  Missing H5Fcreate parameters are provided
                // with default values.
                H5FileId fileId = H5F.create("myCSharp.h5",
                    H5F.CreateMode.ACC_TRUNC);

                // Create a HDF5 group.  
                H5GroupId groupId = H5G.create(fileId, "/cSharpGroup");
                H5GroupId subGroup = H5G.create(groupId, "mySubGroup");

                // Demonstrate getObjectInfo
                ObjectInfo info = H5G.getObjectInfo(fileId, "/cSharpGroup", true);
                Console.WriteLine("cSharpGroup header size is {0}", info.headerSize);
                Console.WriteLine("cSharpGroup nlinks is {0}", info.nHardLinks);
                Console.WriteLine("cSharpGroup fileno is {0} {1}",
                    info.fileNumber[0], info.fileNumber[1]);
                Console.WriteLine("cSharpGroup objno is {0} {1}",
                    info.objectNumber[0], info.objectNumber[1]);
                Console.WriteLine("cSharpGroup type is {0}", info.objectType);


                H5G.close(subGroup);

                // Prepare to create a data space for writing a 1-dimensional 
                // signed integer array.
                long[] dims = new long[RANK];
                dims[0] = DATA_ARRAY_LENGTH;

                // Put descending ramp data in an array so that we can
                // write it to the file.
                int[] dset_data = new int[DATA_ARRAY_LENGTH];
                for (int i = 0; i < DATA_ARRAY_LENGTH; i++)
                    dset_data[i] = DATA_ARRAY_LENGTH - i;

                // Create a data space to accommodate our 1-dimensional array.
                // The resulting H5DataSpaceId will be used to create the 
                // data set.
                H5DataSpaceId spaceId = H5S.create_simple(RANK, dims);

                // Create a copy of a standard data type.  We will use the 
                // resulting H5DataTypeId to create the data set.  We could
                // have  used the HST.H5Type data directly in the call to 
                // H5D.create, but this demonstrates the use of H5T.copy 
                // and the use of a H5DataTypeId in H5D.create.
                H5DataTypeId typeId = H5T.copy(H5T.H5Type.NATIVE_INT);

                // Find the size of the type
                int typeSize = H5T.getSize(typeId);
                Console.WriteLine("typeSize is {0}", typeSize);

                // Set the order to big endian
                H5T.setOrder(typeId, H5T.Order.BE);

                // Set the order to little endian
                H5T.setOrder(typeId, H5T.Order.LE);

                // Create the data set.
                H5DataSetId dataSetId = H5D.create(fileId, "/csharpExample",
                    typeId, spaceId);

                // Write the integer data to the data set.

                H5D.write(dataSetId, new H5DataTypeId(H5T.H5Type.NATIVE_INT),
                    new H5Array<int>(dset_data));

                // If we were writing a single value it might look like this.
                //  int singleValue = 100;
                //  H5D.writeScalar(dataSetId, new H5DataTypeId(H5T.H5Type.NATIVE_INT),
                //     ref singleValue);

                // Create an integer array to receive the read data.
                int[] readDataBack = new int[DATA_ARRAY_LENGTH];

                // Read the integer data back from the data set
                H5D.read(dataSetId, new H5DataTypeId(H5T.H5Type.NATIVE_INT),
                    new H5Array<int>(readDataBack));

                // Echo the data
                for (int i = 0; i < DATA_ARRAY_LENGTH; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(readDataBack[i]);
                }

                // Close all the open resources.
                H5D.close(dataSetId);

                // Reopen and close the data sets to show that we can.
                dataSetId = H5D.open(fileId, "/csharpExample");
                H5D.close(dataSetId);
                dataSetId = H5D.open(groupId, "/csharpExample");
                H5D.close(dataSetId);

                H5S.close(spaceId);
                H5T.close(typeId);
                H5G.close(groupId);

                //int x = 10;
                //H5T.enumInsert<int>(typeId, "myString", ref x);
                //H5G.close(groupId);
                H5GIterateCallback myDelegate;
                myDelegate = myFunction;
                int x = 9;
                int start = 0;
                int index = H5G.iterate(fileId, "/cSharpGroup",myDelegate, x, ref start);

                // Reopen the group id to show that we can.
                groupId = H5G.open(fileId, "/cSharpGroup");
                H5G.close(groupId);

                H5F.close(fileId);

                // Reopen and reclose the file.
                H5FileId openId = H5F.open("myCSharp.h5",
                    H5F.OpenMode.ACC_RDONLY);
                H5F.close(openId);
            }
                // This catches all the HDF exception classes.  Because each call
                // generates unique exception, different exception can be handled
                // separately.  For example, to catch open errors we could have used
                // catch (H5FopenException openException).
            catch (HDFException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Processing complete!");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old but for anyone who still need to work with HDF5 files I have a C# wrapper that encapsulated most of the operations at [github](https://github.com/LiorBanai/Hdf5DotnetWrapper) (based on original work by other person).

There are many examples in the unit tes project.