# Converting H5 to CSV in C#

Tags: c#, csv, hdf5

I am very new to programming and was tasked with creating a program capable of taking a HDF5 file and converting it into a CSV file. I have looked around and found multiple blocks of code ([Convert DataTable to CSV stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888181/convert-datatable-to-csv-stream))
([c# datatable to csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959722/c-sharp-datatable-to-csv))
([HDF5 Example code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939723/c-sharp-hdf5-example-code))
, but I am at a loss for exactly how to go about this. My knowledge includes basic functions, loops, arrays, and a fairly good understanding of complex math (multivariable calc, basic diff-eq, basic matrix operations). I just have 0 idea about built in functionality. Please Help. All explanations are welcome!

PS. I did in fact do research and understand the difference between ASCII and binary as well as HDF5 and CSV files.

Comment: Check http://hdf5.net/

Comment: You may find the utility `h5dump` useful.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in functionality for HDF5 in .NET.
It is not a failing on anybody's part.  There is so much out there!!
So, you either have to create something from scratch, or find a library.
It sounds like you would be better off right now with a library.
Try this one, I haven't used it.  I found it by googling HDF5 and .NET.
http://hdf5.net/
You should also know using the aforementioned library is not going to be a simple project.  It won't be terrible, but try not to get sidetracked by the moving parts.
Accessing a native library from .NET can be tricky.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the hdf5.net library. What you have to do is install the binary and download the HDF5DotNet assembly. Then you create your project and just include the HDF5DotNet.dll as reference. You can then use the HDF5 example code you have already found in order to read the .h5 file. I guarantee it works because I have just done this.