# Getting a substring 2 characters at a time

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a string that looks something like:

```
0122031203
```

I want to be able to parse it and add the following into a list:

```
01
22
03
12
03
```

So, I need to get each 2 characters and extract them.

I tried this:

```
 List<string> mList = new List<string>();
 for (int i = 0; i < _CAUSE.Length; i=i+2) {
     mList.Add(_CAUSE.Substring(i, _CAUSE.Length));
 }
 return mList;
```

but something is not right here, I keep getting the following:

> Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Parameter
>   name: length

Did I get this wrong?

Comment: It's great to use the debugger and particular the intermediate window to understand why things like this aren't working. Like looking at `_CAUSE.Substring(i, _CAUSE.Length)` for example.

Comment: Here are some reusable solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133377/splitting-a-string-number-every-nth-character-number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have may have specified the length incorrectly in the Substring function.

Try the following:

```
List<string> mList = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < _CAUSE.Length; i = i + 2)
{
    mList.Add(_CAUSE.Substring(i, 2));
}

return mList;
```

The length should be 2 if you wish to split this into chunks of 2 characters each.

Comment: You have to stop iterating at `(_CAUSE.Length - 2)` as well, of course

Comment: it works with _CAUSE.LENGTH. thanks Martin!

Answer (score 2):

How about using Linq?

```
string s = "0122031203";
int i = 0;
var mList = s.GroupBy(_ => i++ / 2).Select(g => String.Join("", g)).ToList();
```

Comment: thank you, this looks a little too much for my limited LINQ knowledge :)

Answer (score 0):

when you do the substring, try _CAUSE.SubString(i, 2).

Answer (score 0):

2points: 
1) as previously mentioned, it should be substring(i,2);
2) U should consider the case when the length of ur string is odd. For example 01234: do u want it 01 23 and u'll discard the 4 or do u want it to be 01 23 4 ??