# Convert any value to Hex with variable length

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert values of type int32 of variable size to a hex string with minimal length and 0 padding.

Example: 434 = 01 B2

There are several C# ways, but they all have fixed size, depending on the value type, (Example: Int32 will always give a 4 bytes value like 00 00 00 01 for the number 1).

One can write a code to do it, but I assume there is a shorter way.

thanks

samtal

Comment: Are the spaces in hex string necessary?

Comment: Spaces are not functionally required, but they make it more readable for debugging and maintenance.
Can be left out if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> int x = 434;
> string s = x.ToString("X").PadLeft(5,'0');
> ```

This will produce , 001B2

Comment: Thanks, but this is the easy (and wrong) way, and it does not answer my question.

I have a **variable** value. can be 1, can be 163158, which can be 1 byte or 3 (for 163158 = 02 7D 56).
  
the PadLeft(5,'0') dictates 5 chars.
 
Besides, Hex bytes must be odd number chars, not 5.

I need a solution that will only show the minimum necessary full hex bytes (each 2 chars, padded 0 left), but no padding to the whole number (like 00 00 00 01 for 1).

Comment: Sorry, I had an error in the prev comment.
I meant "Hex bytes must be **EVEN** number chars",

Answer (score 1):

Well, Int3 ὰ's answer is close, just need a further EVEN number handling:

```
int x = 434;
string s = x.ToString("X");
s = s.Length % 2 == 0 ? s : "0" + s;
```

About the spaces issue,  I didn't figure out a very simple way, however, you can look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133377/splitting-a-string-number-every-nth-character-number)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks WAKU for the missing part that was  s = s.Length % 2 == 0 ? s : "0" + s;
I solved the space (or any char) by byte iteration and double padding as follows:
(Not really clean but working)

```
    int i; string d;
        long x = 258458685;
        string s = x.ToString("X");
        s = s.Length % 2 == 0 ? s : "0" + s;
        for (i = 0; i < s.Length  ; i = i + 2)
        {
            d = s.Substring(i ,2);
            Console.Write(d.PadLeft(2, '0').PadLeft(3,' '));
        }
```

Result:  0F 67 C4 3D