# Split string by character count and store in string array

Tags: c#

I have a string like this

```
abcdefghij
```

And I wast to split this string by 3 characters each.
My desired output will be a string array containing this

```
abc
def
ghi
j
```

Is is possible using `string.Split()` method?

Comment: Do you want to split it on every third position or do you want to split it after specific chars like `c`, `f`, `i` in your example?

Comment: string.Split(...) takes at least a character, so i don't see how you could use it. How about using String.Substring(...) in conjunction with a simple loop?

Comment: See
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133377/splitting-a-string-number-every-nth-character-number

Comment: crazy way `string[] t = Regex.Matches("abcdefghij", ".{1,3}").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();`

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov: yes... very crazy

Comment: @Flynn1179 No, it wouldn't. Regex starts new matching where it finished previous one. And it will return `j` as well.

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov: Wouldn't it match `a` first, as the minimum is 1 char?

Comment: @musefan I use greedy, not lazy quantifier. So it would match 3 chars.

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov: Ah yes, of course

Comment: .net 6+: "abcdefghij".Chunk(3).Select(x => new string(x)).ToArray();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<string> GetNextChars ( string str, int iterateCount )
{
    var words = new List<string>();

    for ( int i = 0; i < str.Length; i += iterateCount )
        if ( str.Length - i >= iterateCount ) words.Add(str.Substring(i, iterateCount));
        else words.Add(str.Substring(i, str.Length - i));

    return words;
}
```

This will avoid `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` in @Sajeetharan's answer.

**Edit:** Sorry for completely dumb previous answer of mine :) this is supposed to do the trick.

Comment: Doesn't even compile... mismatch on the return type. For some reason @Sajeetharan edited out the key bit that would make this work, which just made their answer doubly bad

Comment: All you needed to do was add `yield` to your previous answer ;)

Comment: Sadly I don't know the usage of the `yield` keyword. I will certainly look into that. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

This code will group the chars in groups of 3, and convert each group to a string.

```
string s = "abcdefghij";

var split = s.Select((c, index) => new {c, index})
    .GroupBy(x => x.index/3)
    .Select(group => group.Select(elem => elem.c))
    .Select(chars => new string(chars.ToArray()));

foreach (var str in split)
    Console.WriteLine(str);
```

prints

```
abc
def
ghi
j
```

Fiddle: http://dotnetfiddle.net/1PgFu7

Comment: No need for `.ToCharArray()`.

Comment: Seems a bit overkill for me... just for the sake of using LINQ

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov Good point, edited.

Comment: @musefan It's not for the sake of using Linq, it's for the sake of clarity and readibility. You group the chars into groups of 3, and then merge the chars. Seems simple to me.

Comment: Your code solved my problem. thx u

Comment: Can do it without this many selects, surely?

Answer (score 3):

Using a bit of Linq

```
static IEnumerable<string> Split(string str)
{
    while (str.Length > 0)
    {
        yield return new string(str.Take(3).ToArray());
        str = new string(str.Skip(3).ToArray());
    }
}
```

Here is the [Demo](http://ideone.com/O6CVQX)

Answer (score 1):

```
IEnumerable<string> Split(string str) {
    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i += 3)
        yield return str.Substring(i, Math.Min(str.Length - i, 3));
}
```

Comment: `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`

Comment: -1 This doesn't work with the input example provided by the OP

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't believe it is possible using just `string.Split()`. But it is simple enough to create your own function...

```
string[] MySplit(string input)
{
   List<string> results = new List<string>();
   int count = 0;
   string temp = "";

   foreach(char c in input)
   {
      temp += c;
      count++;
      if(count == 3)
      {
         result.Add(temp);
         temp = "";
         count = 0;
      }
   }

   if(temp != "")
      result.Add(temp);

   return result.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: I'd use a string builder or a `char[]` rather than repeated concatenations like this.

Comment: @Rawling: Maybe... not really worth worrying about it in my opinion, but obviously no harm going the extra step if it suits your preference