# Split and append a string?

Tags: c#, string

Right now I take in a string like this `"112233 112233 112233 112233"`, and I split it into an array like this:

```
string text = ProcessString("112233 112233");
string[] dates = text.Split(' ');
```

And that works great, but I want to use string builder to build my string so they would end up like `11-22-33 11-22-33` etc.

So I did try this:

```
static string ProcessString(string input)
{
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(input.Length * 3 / 2);

    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        if ((i > 0) & (i % 2 == 0))
            buffer.Append("-");
        buffer.Append(input[i]);
    }
    return buffer.ToString();
}
```

It works, but it does not match the expected output of:

```
11-22-33 
11-22-33
```

My current output is:

```
11-22-33- 
1-12-23-3
-11-22-33
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: If there's only three elements, take it out of the for loop and use string.Format. string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", element1, element2, element3)

Comment: Why not split on space first, then insert the dashes?

Comment: string text = "112233 112233 112233 112233";
             string[] dates = text.Split(' ').Select(x => x.Substring(1,2) + "-" + x.Substring(2,2) + "-" + x.Substring(4, 2)).ToArray();

Comment: @jdweng That really should be an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: @IanP the 3 strings were just there because I wanted to test, I don't want to hard code the values really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can process a single string simply by iterating and collecting size-2 substrings of the string, and then joining them by the `-` character:

```
string s = "112233";

List<string> parts = new List<string>(s.Length / 2);
for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i += 2)
    parts.Add(s.Substring(i, 2));

Console.WriteLine(string.Join("-", parts)); // 11-22-33
```

So, for your full problem, you could do this:

```
static string ProcessString(string input)
{
    var segments = input.Split(' ').Select(s =>
    {
        List<string> parts = new List<string>(s.Length / 2);
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i += 2)
            parts.Add(s.Substring(i, 2));
        return string.Join("-", parts);
    });

    return string.Join(" ", segments);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can i offer you another Regex + LINQ approach?

```
var newDates = dates.Select(d => Regex.Replace(d, ".{2}", "$0-").Trim('-'));
string result = string.Join(" ", newDates);
```

But i like [this extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4133475/284240) more because it's readable and re-usable:

```
public static IEnumerable<String> SplitInParts(this String s, Int32 partLength)
{
    if (s == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("s");
    if (partLength <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("Part length has to be positive.", "partLength");

    for (var i = 0; i < s.Length; i += partLength)
        yield return s.Substring(i, Math.Min(partLength, s.Length - i));
}
```

Then the code is even easier:

```
var newDates = dates.Select(d => string.Join("-", d.SplitInParts(2)));
string result = string.Join(" ", newDates);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about regex:

```
string s = "112233";
string pattern = @"\d{2}\B";
string result = Regex.Replace(s, pattern, m => m.Value + "-");
```

Comment: I like this solution; it also works for the original string `"112233 112233"`.

Answer (score 0):

I have this approach :

```
       string input = "112233 445566 778899 101010";
       string[] dates = input.Split(' ');

       foreach (string date in dates){
           Console.WriteLine(date);
           string result = date.Substring(0, 2) + '-' + date.Substring(2, 2) + "-" + date.Substring(4, 2);
           Console.WriteLine(result);
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.ConvertAll`:

```
string str = "112233 112233 112233 112233";
string[] dates = str.Split();

dates = Array.ConvertAll(dates, s => s.Insert(4, "-").Insert(2, "-"));

foreach (var s in dates)
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```