# I want split the number into hundreds, not thousands

Tags: c#, .net

When fromatting integer number (e.g. `1234567890`) I want groups of size `2` (hundreds), not of size `3` (thousands). I have tried something like this

```
int number = 1234567890;
string value = string.Format("{0:#,###0}", number);
```

Desired `value`:

```
12,34,56,78,90
```

Actual `value`:

```
1,234,567,890
```

Comment: Please post code of what you have tried so far

Comment: Nope, not a clue what you're actually asking about here. Are you trying to write a *function*? If so, what is the *signature* of that function, and *what have you tried*? Try to give us a clear *specification* of what you're trying to do, rather than just putting an "example" in front of us and expecting us to *deduce* the specification.

Comment: int number = 1234567890
 value = string.Format("{0:#,###0}", number);

Comment: _Research; experiment; debug; ship!_  [ask]

Comment: **[edit]** your question to show your code, don't try to put it in comments.

Comment: Your question is not clear on many points, for instance are the input and outputs `string` or `int` or a combination? Always be specific and prefer C# over a description.

Comment: @KaviyarasuN this problem has already been solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4133475/4329813

Comment: Look into `System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo`

Comment: thank you all, and @popsiporkkanaa its working fine thanks.This is my first question here So, let me know if anything wrong in my question i will correct it in next time.

Comment: @KaviyarasuN You're welcome. As MickyD has mentioned, you should read the How to Ask (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first. Your question may already has been answered before in a different way but the main point is that you should show your effort of trying to solve it. And in the end, please don't forget to mark "Accepted" to someone's answer or vote a comment as helpful

Comment: @DmitryBychenko - an awful lot of guesswork. Does the OP really have "an integer number" or was it a string?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {           
            NumberFormatInfo nfi = new CultureInfo("en-US").NumberFormat;

            // Displays a value with the default separator (".").
            Int64 myInt = 123456789012345;
            Console.WriteLine(myInt.ToString("N", nfi));

            // Displays the same value with different groupings.
            int[] mySizes1 = { 2, 3, 4 };
            int[] mySizes2 = { 2, 2 };
            nfi.NumberGroupSizes = mySizes1;
            Console.WriteLine(myInt.ToString("N", nfi));
            nfi.NumberGroupSizes = mySizes2;
            Console.WriteLine(myInt.ToString("N", nfi));
            ReadLine();
            }
```

for further info plz refer this link :- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbergroupsizes(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: And now print that (Console.WritelIne). What do you see?

Comment: You could use `int[] mySizes2 = { 2 };` for the same effect (the desired result of the OP)

Comment: yes and use "N0" instead of "N" if you don't want decimal digits.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many logic for doing this. I found following one.
I assume you have string.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string numbers = "1234567890";

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", CustomSplit(numbers, 1)));
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", CustomSplit(numbers, 2)));
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", CustomSplit(numbers, 3)));

    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static List<string> CustomSplit(string Input, int Length)
{
    List<string> result = new List<string>();


    string[] split = new string[Input.Length / Length + (Input.Length % Length == 0 ? 0 : 1)];

    for (int i = 0; i < split.Length; i++)
    {
    result.Add( Input.Substring(i * Length, i * Length + Length > Input.Length ? 1 : Length));
    }

    return result;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0
12,34,56,78,90
123,456,789,0
```