# Split text into 4 fields who length is 20 symbols

Tags: c#

**First:** *I know how to split string by length. Task is not about to split text just by length.*

---

I have a text who comes from three database columns, let's call them data fields:

1. Company name
2. company registration number aka VAT
3. Company address

I need to print this data via cash register on recipe. I have some limitations (set by cash register software/driver):

- I have 4 fields (4 lines), to print customer info
- each field/line length is 20 symbols
- company registration number always is one word, example: AB0123456789

To send customer data to cash register, I must specify file in following format:

`1,"row 1","row 2","row 3","row 4",0,0.00`

Here is description of format:

- `1` - Customer number/ID, integer, max 16 numbers
- `row 1/2/3/4` - string, max 20 symbols each, can be empty
- `0` - discount number
- `0.00` - customer
  discount (%)

I must place text from database to four fields with some rules:

- if possible do not split VAT number

I tried various things to split all text to 4 fields, but not so successful.

There can be case when total data length is more than 80 symbols, in this case user can modify each field.

Maybe someone have some (better) suggestions how to split text... Of course this can be achieved with lot of `if`s. But that is ugly.

Example data: input: [MyCompany LTD] [AB0123456789] [Not so long address in country]
Output:

`MyCompany LTD
AB0123456789
Not so long
address in country`

Example 2: [My investment properties LTD] [AB0123456789] [street 24 mycity 2233 country]
output:

`My investment proper
ties LTD
AB0123456789 street
24 mycity 2233 count`

If split VAT number, then it is possible to fit all information, but it looks ugly:

`My investment proper
ties LTD AB012345678
9 street 24 mycity
2233 country`

If possible, do not split vat number at all.

My variant:

```
class ChdCustomer
{
    private List<string> outputLines = new List<string>();
    private bool allFit = true;
    private string tmpLine = "";

    public string Line1()
    {
        if (outputLines.Count >= 1) return outputLines[0]; else return "";
    }

    public string Line2()
    {
        if (outputLines.Count >= 2) return outputLines[1]; else return "";
    }

    public string Line3()
    {
        if (outputLines.Count >= 3) return outputLines[2]; else return "";
    }

    public string Line4()
    {
        if (outputLines.Count >= 4) return outputLines[3]; else return "";
    }

    public ChdCustomer()
    {
    }

    public ChdCustomer(string name, string vat, string address)
    {
        AddNameAndVat(name, vat);
        AddAddress(address);
    }

    public bool FitAll()
    {
        return allFit;
    }

    public void AddAddress(string text)
    {
        if (!allFit)
            return;

        int fc = outputLines.Count * 20;


        if (fc == 60)
        {
            fc -= 20 - outputLines[2].Length;
        }
        if (fc < text.Length || fc > 80)
        {
            allFit = false;
            return;
        }


        fc = (80 - fc) / 20; // free lines

        tmpLine = "";
        string[] k = text.Split(' ');


        foreach (string s in k)
        {
            if ((tmpLine + s).Length <= 20)
            {
                tmpLine += s + " ";
            }
            else
            {
                if (fc > 0)
                    outputLines.Add(tmpLine.Trim());
                tmpLine = s + " ";
                fc--;
            }
        }

        if (!outputLines[outputLines.Count - 1].Contains(tmpLine))
        {
            outputLines.Add(tmpLine);
        }


        if (outputLines.Count > 4)
        {
            allFit = false;
        }
    }

    public void AddNameAndVat(string name, string vat)
    {
        if ((name + vat).Length < 20)
        {
            outputLines.Add(name + " " + vat);
        }
        else
        {
            if (name.Length <= 20)
            {
                outputLines.Add(name);
                outputLines.Add(vat);
            }
            else
            {
                if (name.Length <= 40)
                {
                    string[] k = name.Split(' ');

                    foreach (string s in k)
                    {
                        if ((tmpLine + s).Length <= 20)
                        {
                            tmpLine += s + " ";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            tmpLine = tmpLine.Trim();

                            string remaining = name.Substring(tmpLine.Length).Trim();
                            if (remaining.Length <= 20)
                            {
                                outputLines.Add(tmpLine);
                                outputLines.Add(remaining);
                                outputLines.Add(vat);
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                outputLines.Add(name.Substring(0, 20));
                                outputLines.Add(name.Substring(20));
                                outputLines.Add(vat);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    allFit = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are many utilities, like [`TextFieldParser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser), that already do this.

Comment: Create a class for one recipe and put all data into the class.  The write an output method that writes all the properties.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Splitting a string / number every Nth Character / Number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133377/splitting-a-string-number-every-nth-character-number)

Comment: @Josh, no. I want a bit smarter "splitter", not just by position. of course it would work, but output is ugly

Comment: Please provide sample input and expected output

Comment: If you want this sort of highly custom behavior where only some words can be split and some cannot then you will need those nasty chain of if statements you mentioned before. .NET doesn't have a built in method for your highly specialized scenario.

Comment: Are there always four lines?  How are the 4 lines separated?  By a blank line?

Comment: @jdweng It's four lines. like in document. Line max length is 20 symbols.

Comment: What does file look like when there is more than one company is in a file?

Comment: When i send data to cash register, i have 4 fields available for customer data: `1,"20 symbols here","20 symbols here","20 symbols here","20 symbols here",0,0.00` this i cannot change.

Comment: Some lines have more than 20 characters.  Look again at you expected results.

Comment: I added a 2nd solution to your code with the way I would write code.

Comment: @jdweng Your "Solution 2" should be posted as an answer (with some annotation and/or explanation), not edited into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution :

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] inputs = { 
                                "[MyCompany LTD] [AB0123456789] [Not so long address in country]",
                                "[My investment properties LTD] [AB0123456789] [street 24 mycity 2233 country]"

                              };
            foreach (string input in inputs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Parsing : '{0}'", input);

                string[] splitArray = input.Split(new char[] { '[', ']' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                string remainder = "";
                int index = 0;
                string line = "";
                do
                {
                    if (index < splitArray.Length)
                    {
                        line = remainder + splitArray[index];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        line = remainder;
                    }
                    remainder = string.Empty;
                    if (line.Trim().Length > 0)
                    {

                        if (line.Length > 20)
                        {
                            remainder = line.Substring(20);
                            line = line.Substring(0, 20);
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", line);
                    }
                    if (index < splitArray.Length) index++;

                } while ((index <= 4) && ((index < splitArray.Length) || (remainder.Length > 0)));
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: With second example, second row is `ties LTDties LTD`

Comment: I moved one line of code :  remainder = string.Empty;