# How do i split a text 2 by 2?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, split

The variable is: Hello
The result I want:

```
split[0] = he;
split[1] = ll;
split[2] = o + ( space );
```

I tried this code:

```
string[] split = new string[text.Length / 2 + (text.Length % 2 == 0 ? 0 : 1)];
for (int i = 0; i < split.Length; i++)
{
  split[i] = text.Substring(i, i + 2 > text.Length ? 1 : 2);
}
```

The output is "He el lo" (it doubles the second character).

Comment: You may want to add your programming language as tag to your question.

Comment: Hint: run the code mentally, on a piece of paper. And note: it would help if you specified the language you are using, for example using the corresponding tag. And:  you could make your life much easier if you just added a " " space in case the length of your input isnt even.

Comment: And hint: check out your code, and ask yourself what values `i` will go to. And what values it *should* go to.

Comment: I don't get why "Hello" gets split this way. Where does the extra space come from? Was it in the original string? Or is it just used as padding for when there is an odd number of characters?

Comment: If the variable.lenght / 2 haves decimals, then it adds space on variable

Comment: i already added this part

Comment: odd or not, it doubles the second character

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Splitting a string / number every Nth Character / Number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133377/splitting-a-string-number-every-nth-character-number)

Comment: it became horror code for me, i cant understand it

Comment: I was [bored](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6i9rDw).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
string input = "Hello"
string[] split = new string[input.Length / 2 + (input.Length % 2 == 0 ? 0 : 1)];
for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i+=2)
{
    split[i/2] = input.Substring(i, i + 2 > input.Length ? 1 : 2);
}
```

This steps through the input string in increments of two and takes 2 characters at a time.