# Dynamic Generation of All Possible Combinations of Index of an Array

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

My task is to generate all possible index combinations of an array, wherein the array might be a single, 2D, 3D, 4D ... nD array with different number of elements. For now, I can only support single, 2D and 3D array using nested for loop.

Example:

```
byte[,,] sampleArray = new byte[5,4,3];

Generated Index Combinations:
sampleArray[0,0,0]
sampleArray[0,0,1]
sampleArray[0,0,2]
sampleArray[0,1,0]
sampleArray[0,1,1]
sampleArray[0,1,2]
sampleArray[0,2,0]
sampleArray[0,2,1]
sampleArray[0,2,2]
sampleArray[0,3,0]
sampleArray[0,3,1]
sampleArray[0,3,2]
sampleArray[1,0,0]
sampleArray[1,0,1]
sampleArray[1,0,2]
sampleArray[1,1,0]
sampleArray[1,1,1]
sampleArray[1,1,2]
sampleArray[1,2,0]
sampleArray[1,2,1]
sampleArray[1,2,2]
sampleArray[1,3,0]
sampleArray[1,3,1]
sampleArray[1,3,2]
sampleArray[2,0,0]
sampleArray[2,0,1]
sampleArray[2,0,2]
sampleArray[2,1,0]
sampleArray[2,1,1]
sampleArray[2,1,2]
sampleArray[2,2,0]
sampleArray[2,2,1]
sampleArray[2,2,2]
sampleArray[2,3,0]
sampleArray[2,3,1]
sampleArray[2,3,2]
sampleArray[3,0,0]
sampleArray[3,0,1]
sampleArray[3,0,2]
sampleArray[3,1,0]
sampleArray[3,1,1]
sampleArray[3,1,2]
sampleArray[3,2,0]
sampleArray[3,2,1]
sampleArray[3,2,2]
sampleArray[3,3,0]
sampleArray[3,3,1]
sampleArray[3,3,2]
sampleArray[4,0,0]
sampleArray[4,0,1]
sampleArray[4,0,2]
sampleArray[4,1,0]
sampleArray[4,1,1]
sampleArray[4,1,2]
sampleArray[4,2,0]
sampleArray[4,2,1]
sampleArray[4,2,2]
sampleArray[4,3,0]
sampleArray[4,3,1]
sampleArray[4,3,2]
```

My Code:

```
     protected void GenerateIndexCombinations(int indexCounter, 
     ref List<List<int>> indexList, Array arr, ref List<int> index)
        {
            int dimSize1 = arr.GetLength(0);
            int dimSize2 = 0;
            int dimSize3 = 0;
            if (indexCounter > 1)
            {
                dimSize2 = arr.GetLength(1);
                if (indexCounter > 2)
                {
                    dimSize3 = arr.GetLength(2);
                }
            }

            for (int a = 0; a < dimSize1; a++)
            {
                if (dimSize2 > 0)
                {
                    for (int b = 0; b < dimSize2; b++)
                    {
                        if (dimSize3 > 0)
                        {
                            for (int c = 0; c < dimSize3; c++)
                            {
                                index = new List<int>();
                                index.Add(a);
                                index.Add(b);
                                index.Add(c);
                                indexList.Add(index);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            index = new List<int>();
                            index.Add(a);
                            index.Add(b);
                            indexList.Add(index);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    index = new List<int>();
                    index.Add(a);
                    indexList.Add(index);
                }
            }
        }
```

Where:

int indexCounter is number of dimension. 

Array arr is the array accessed by using reflection:

```
Array arr = fieldInfoArray[j].GetValue(_classInstance) as Array;
```

`ref List<List<int>> indexList` will be the container of the combinations.

`ref List<int> index` is the individual number added to the indexList.

Since the dimension size is not fixed, as well the number of elements per dimension, I want to generate the combinations dynamically to replace my nested for loop, Is there a way to do it?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eric Lippert has [blogged](http://ericlippert.com/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq/) about exactly this problem. In your specific case you're looking for the Cartesian product of `Enumerable.Range(0, 5)`, `Enumerable.Range(0, 4)`, and `Enumerable.Range(0, 3)`. In general, you want something like this:

```
var dimensions = 
     Enumerable.Range(0, array.Rank)
               .Select(r => Enumerable.Range(0, array.GetLength(r)));
```

And then invoke Eric's method on `dimensions`. Here, I'm using [`Array.Rank`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.rank.aspx) to get the dimensionality of the matrix, and then using [`Array.GetLength`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlength.aspx) to get the length along each dimension, and then dynamically generating the sequences that we need to compute the Cartesian product of. So, for each dimension, we project that dimension to the sequence of valid indexes along that dimension for `array`. Thus, for

```
T[,,...,] array = new T[a_1, a_2, ..., a_n];
```

we end up with `dimensions` equaling the sequence

```
(Enumerable.Range(0, a_1),
 Enumerable.Range(0, a_2),
 .
 .
 .,
 Enumerable.Range(0, a_n)
)

using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;

static class EnumerableExtensions {
    // credit: Eric Lippert
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CartesianProduct<T>(
        this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences
    ) {
        IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> emptyProduct = 
            new[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() };
        return sequences.Aggregate(
            emptyProduct,
            (accumulator, sequence) =>
                 from accseq in accumulator
                 from item in sequence
                 select accseq.Concat(new[] { item })
        );
    }
}

class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        int[,,] array = new int[5, 4, 3];
        var dimensions = 
            Enumerable.Range(0, array.Rank)
                      .Select(r => Enumerable.Range(0, array.GetLength(r)));
        var indexes = dimensions.CartesianProduct();
        foreach(var index in indexes) {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", index));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jason, I tried using the codes in the blog, but I still can't get the combinations. Sorry, since I am new in C# coding. :(

Comment: @Ron Reyes: Sorry to hear that. My code works as is, combined with Eric's code, but I've provided you a full sample nonetheless.

Comment: Ok, I'll Try it again, I just don't know how to see the results using Console.WriteLine.

Comment: @Ron Reyes: I'm not sure what you mean. In Visual Studio, start a new solution, make it a console application, and paste the code above exactly as. Then, compile and run the application.

Comment: It shows this in the output:
System.Linq.Enumerable+<ConcatIterator>d__71`1[System.Int32]

Comment: @ron: I don't think that you pasted the code exactly as is. In particular, I think that you changed `Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", index));` to `Console.WriteLine(index);`. `index` is a sequence of specific coordinates into the array, so it looks like `(0, 1, 2)`, for example. If you try to print out `index`, you get the type of `index`, which is concrete a `IEnumerable<T>` from Eric's code. You have to format that sequence into a meaningful `string`. One way to do that is iterate over the sequence adding a comma between entries. `String.Join` is a simple way to do that.

Comment: I tried running your codes as is in .NET Framework 4.5 and it works fine. I think I get the error "The best overloaded method match for 'string.Join(string, string[])' has some invalid arguments" and "Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>' to 'string[]'" because I tried to run it at .NET Framework 3.5.

Comment: @ron: Yes, the overload of `String.Join` that I'm using wasn't added until .NET 4.5. If you need to use .NET 3.5, change `index` to `index.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray()` in the call to `String.Join`. This is covered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1890104/45914).